# Converting an integer to an iterator for std::list

Tags: c++, iterator

I have the simple code below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> ints = { 3, 6, 1, 5, 8 };
    int index;

    index = 2;
    std::list<int>::iterator it = ints.begin() + index;
    cout << "Element at index " << index << " is " << *it << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

On [compiling](https://ideone.com/AfsPVG), it says:

> error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::__cxx11::list::iterator’ {aka ‘std::_List_iterator’} and ‘int’) 
>     std::list::iterator it = ints.begin() + index; 
>                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~

I understand what the compiler is trying to say, but I am unsure how to resolve it.  How do I convert the `int` to an `iterator` and get the element at that index?  I did look for similar questions, but most of them seek the conversion in the opposite direction which can be done using [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance), while the remaining were for different containers.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Linked lists don't support random access, so there is no `operator+` for such iterators

Comment: For linked lists' iterators you'll need to perform unary increment or decrement `n` times: `for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { it++; }`

Comment: But @JohnFilleau, if I do that, then wouldn't I be conceptually doing a _random access_?

Comment: Don't ask me, I'm just a computer engineer. Looks like `std::next` is also nice: `auto it = std::next(ints.begin(), 2);`

Comment: "Random access" usually means that every index takes the same amount of time to access. You can access indices "randomly" and expect your algorithm to not slow down. `std::next(ints.begin(), i)` takes longer the bigger `i` is. If you want to write efficient code, you cannot use this kind of indexing too often. Note that this definition still leaves room for interpretation. At the strictest, not even arrays or `std::vector`s have random access, because of issues with caching etc, even though we normally think of them as having it. It depends on how finely grained your point of view is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next).

If you think of `distance` as the operator `-` between two iterators, then `next`, `prev`, and `advance` are respectively the `+`, `-`, and `+=` between an iterator and an integer.
These functions are meant to treat all iterators the same way, even though the complexity of operations is different for different iterators. For a `std::list`, which uses "forward iterators", these are all linear. For a `std::vector`, which uses "random-access iterators", these are all constant.

Comment: Great!  I did not know about this method. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Converting an integer to an iterator for std::list

Integers and iterators are quite separate concepts, so it is unclear what meaning such conversion would have. How does one convert a coconut into transitivity?

> ... and get the element at that index?

Now, this makes a bit more sense. List element do not have indices however. But presumably by index `i`, you mean the `i`th (zero based) successive element from beginning.

The standard library has a function for that: `std::next`. What this does (with non-random access iterators) is increment the iterator for given number of repetitions in a loop. Intuitively, the asymptotic complexity of such operation is linear.